# ZF2 : nested fieldsets; binding and hydration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to deal with some fieldsets witch are bind with the same table entity, and nested in some other one.
Exemple:

Model:

```
Table Building
-> Name
-> Description
-> street name
-> street Number
-> consierge's phone
-> level count
-> height
-> Year of construction
```

All this fields are in one table but i whant to use multiples fieldset, like this for exemple:

```
descriptionBlgFieldset
->name
->description

AddressBlgFieldset
->street Name
->street Number
-> consierge's phone

FeaturesBlgFieldset
-> level count
-> height
-> Year of construction
```

Then i whant to blend those in some other field set, for exemple description with address, or description with features, or all of them. I was thinking this was peace of cake, but i  dont know how to deal for the binding:

```
echo $form->get('building')->get('address')->get('streetNumber)
```

give me:

```
<input name="building[addresse][streetNumber]" />
```

But it's must be:

```
<input name="building[streetNumber]" />
```

I what thinking about the "set_as_base_fieldset" option, but it's only work when I'm hadding a fieldset in a form object, not in a fieldset.

How could i do that? (i hope this whas clear enought)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `building[streetNumber]` then you don't want to use a Fieldset. That's really all there is to it. A `Zend\Form\Fieldset` is an Element that encapsulates a set of properties that are standalone / their own object. For example:

```
Table Buildings
- id
- attr1
- addr_id

Table Addresses
- id
- name
- nr
```

In this case you'd have an `AddressFieldset`. But this isn't what you want. **I assume you only divided this into fieldsets to have an impact on the default rendering.** This is a mis-use of `Zend\Form\Fieldset`. You simply will have to render your form differently like

```
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo "<fieldset>\n";
echo "    <legend>Address</legend>\n";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('streetName'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('streetNuber'));
echo "</fieldset>\n";
echo "<fieldset>\n";
echo "    <legend>Features</legend>\n";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('levelCount'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('height'));
echo "</fieldset>\n";
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: aw, that's exactly what i whanted to avoid ^^
and i whanted to use field set to easly use validationGroup method...there isn't a other solutions?

Comment: because i'll have sometime many diffrent view affecting same table...and i dont whant to change all of them every time i add or remove a field

Comment: ok, i found my solution: partial view en use validationGroup inside my form.Thank's!